# Representing a Continuous Case as a Discrete Case

Tags: probability

I was going over some study problems and came across the following:

> Imagine a TV game show where each contestant $i$ spins an infinitely
>   calibrated wheel of fortune, which assigns him/her with some real
>   number with a value between 1 and 100. All values are equally likely
>   and the value obtained by each contestant is independent of the value
>   obtained by any other contestant.
>
> Find $P(X1< X2)$, the probability that Contestant 2 beats (spins a higher number than) Contestant 1

And the solution says the following:

$P(X1< X2)=(\frac{1}{100} \cdot \frac{99}{100})+(\frac{1}{100} \cdot \frac{98}{100})+...+(\frac{1}{100} \cdot \frac{2}{100})+(\frac{1}{100} \cdot \frac{1}{100})=0.495$

It looks as if they modeled the wheel as a die with 100 faces, then calculated the probability that Contestant 2 wins for each value that Contestant 1 could roll. I don't understand their reasoning here. Why are they able to model a continuous case as a discrete case?

Comment: They shouldn't be able to.  They must have misspoken when they said "a *real* value between $1$ and $100$" when they intended to say "an *integer* value between $1$ and $100$."  If they really did intend for every real number to be possible, then the probability that contestant 2 beats contestant 1 should be precisely $0.5$ since it is *almost-impossible* that they roll the same value (*i.e. with probability zero*) and they should have the same chances of winning.

Comment: As an aside, for the discrete case, it is *much* easier to recognize that they have the same chances of winning and one of them will win so long as they don't tie.  They tie with probability $\frac{1}{100}$ so contestant two wins with probability $\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{100})=\frac{99}{200}=0.495$